# Put hard coded values in sqlite database of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, schema

I am making a survey application in rails, where users will take a survey. My back end will analyze the results of mutliple people taking these surveys. The Survey will have four scenarios. Each scenario will have three options to choose from. These options have a lot of text. I would like to put these options in as hard coded values within the database (in my case sqlite), so I can pull the options and scenarios from the database but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can put pre-necessary values on db/seeds.rb. Than you need to run `rake db:seed` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can put pre-necessary values on db/seeds.rb. Than you need to run `rake db:seed` command after `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:setup` is the more conventional command, as it essentially runs `db:schema:load db:seed`